# How to get the Text of TextBlock (TextBlock is Content of Button)

Tags: c#, wpf, button, textblock

a `TextBlock` is inside a `Button` as `content`.

I want the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`. Please kindly advice how I can solve this.

Below code only return `ct` as `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock`

```
string ct = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
```

Of course, the `Content` of `Button` is really a `TextBlock` `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock`
I found very similar case in stackoverflow but people only provided wrong answer.

Comment: have you tried `string ct = ((sender as Button).Content as TextBlock).Content;` ?

Comment: @ericosg, You're the first person submitted right answer. I cordially thank All 3 persons who provided excellent, right answer. I regret that you only wrote as comment not as answer..Thank you so much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `Content` of the `Button` is `TextBlock` you should consider `(sender as Button).Content` as a `TextBlock` then use the `Text` property like this:

```
string ct = ((sender as Button).Content as TextBlock).Text;
```

Comment: So many thanks for your excellent, kindness. All 3 persons brought right answer to me..Have comfortable day !

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to solve your problem. First one is just cast `Button` content and get the text:

```
var button = (sender as Button);
if(button == null)
{
    // handle this scenario
}

var textBlockContent = button.Content as TextBlock;
if(textBlockContent == null)
{
    // handle this scenario
}

var ct = textBlockContent.Text;
```

The second one you can find your `TextBlock` [by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) or just reference it if you have event handler in the same control:

```
var textblock = (TextBlock)this.FindName("YourTextBlockName");
if(textblock == null)
{
    // handle this scenario
}

var ct = textblock.Text;
```

Also you can try to change your XAML code to store just a text in your button:

```
<Button Content="YourText" Backround="..." Foreground="..." Style="..." />
```

Comment: So many thanks for your excellent, kindness. All 3 persons brought right answer to me..Have comfortable day !